# React function prop returns _function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

I have a really weird issue,

I have a component that receives a function prop:

```
<MyMenu
  prop1={prop1}
  myFunction={() => myFunction()}>
</MyMenu>
```

myFunction is defined in the class component that wrap MyMenu, and is being sent down as a prop to other different components in that class, it works.

But for some weird reason, when I try to invoke myFunction() inside MyMenu, I get a typeerror saying its not a function.

When I console.log(myFunction), I get:

```
myFunction() {
   return _myFunction()
 }
```

Anyone has any idea whats happening here?
Thanks!

Comment: Always listen to the language. If it says that `myFunction` isn't a function, then it has to be something else.

How are you verifying that it is a function? What does `console.log(typeof this.props.myFunction)` show?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description

> myFunction is defined in the class component that wrap MyMenu, and is
>   being sent down as a prop to other different components in that class,

I'm infering that `myFunction` is a method in the parent class that renders `MyMenu`.

You are passing an anonymous function that calls `myFunction` into `MyMeny`

```
<MyMenu
  myFunction={() => myFunction()}>
</MyMenu>
```

However, since `myFunction` is a method, it's not available as a free variable and is only accessible via `this` of the parent class.

So you are passing a function into `MyMenu`, but that function is then trying to call something that isn't a function.

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
<MyMenu
  myFunction={() => this.myFunction()}>
{/*                 ^^^^            */}
</MyMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but MyMenu is actually a "dumb" component that gets myFunction as  a prop, so inside MyMenu "myFucntion" is being used as props.myFunction.